# Is it possible to add custom set of icons to unicode?

Tags: unicode

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but is it possible to add a custom set of emoji-like icons to unicode, so that I can display icons in plain text format (so creating a font library won't work) with other characters from unicode?

I'd like to display something like this:

```
[a small, ideally colored stackoverflow icon as a character]stackoverflow
```

Comment: You are allowed to use the [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) for anything you like. It is not uncommon to [put custom icons there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx).

Comment: Emoji used to be implemented as private use characters before they were added to Unicode. On the latest Android, the flag emoji still are, even though you can also make flags with the regional indicator symbol letters.